# How to substring in RegExp?

Tags: regex

Does anyone how to know to substring in regular expression? I am currently profiling data and i saw different format such as :

> EB0000000
>
> EB00000000PHL00000000F00000000
>
> P0000000A

When I used my expression:
`\b(?:[A-Z]{1}\d{7}[A-Z]{1}|[A-Z]{1}\d{7,8}|[A-Z]{2}\d{6}|[A-Z]{2}\d{7,8})\b`

I captured the first and last sample, but the second looks improper data but i still want to capture EB and those 8 digits before PHL. Is it possible in regexp? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is it so hard to write? Maybe there are some lines nearby that should not fall into the selection?

```
\b[A-Z\d]{8,}\b
```

Comment: Yes sir. There are lots of data that should not fall into selection

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you could change the order of the alternatives to put the most specific one at the beginning and then remove the word boundary at the end.

Note that you can omit `{1}`

```
\b(?:[A-Z]{2}\d{7,8}|[A-Z]\d{7}[A-Z]|[A-Z]\d{7,8}|[A-Z]{2}\d{6})
```

In parts

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Z]{2}\d{7,8}` Match 2 times A-Z and 7-8 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Z]\d{7}[A-Z]` Match A-Z, 7 digits and A-Z
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Z]\d{7,8}` Match A-Z and 7-8 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Z]{2}\d{6}` Match 2 times A-Z and 6 digits
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bj1BpA/1)

Comment: Thanks again sir! Hmm.. this is different but is there any possibility to capture combination of letters and numbers like EC80T7666.. Im planning to put \w{9} but then again there's a data that should have not fall into selection.

Comment: `\w` can also match `_` I updated the pattern based on your initial pattern which allows for certain selections. You would have to specify which selections you would further allow or specify a more global pattern if the logic allows it.

Comment: I enhanced my pattern and I want this one [A-Z]{2,3}(?: )?\d{6,9} to specify a more global pattern as you say sir.

Comment: Based on that example, this could be the more global variant `\b[A-Z]+ ?\d+` https://regex101.com/r/v9pgfP/1